# react-native app crashes when distributed

Tags: ios, react-native, ad-hoc-distribution, google-fabric, hockeyapp

When running the app on a simulator (or on a connected iPhone), I have no trouble running the application.

However when I archive the app in xcode (build succeeds) and distribute it using either HockeyApp or Fabric, the app installs just fine, but upon opening the app, it crashes right after the splash screen.

- The log-file that is being generated on the iPhone does not give any useful information
- On the Fabric/HockeyApp dashboard no crashes are being registered.

Any advice on how to get a stack trace or other useful crash log?

Comment: Look into Sentry.

Comment: If you have some native code (Java or C#), double check them. I had the same issue and the problem was with my Java code.

Answer (score 2):

When running the react-native app using `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`, I was able to reproduce the error in the simulator and fix the JS error that was somehow not appearing running in debug mode. Logs for the Simulator can be found at

> ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator